# Formatting references and text citations for journal submission

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib

I am preparing a manuscript to submit to the Journal of Biogeography. The requirements for formatting references are very specific though - particularly the in-text citations - and I am worried that I am going to struggle to meet the requirements using LaTeX.

Are the below requirements going to be an issue for a beginner/intermediate LaTeX user?

> **References:**
>
> References are styled according to the sixth edition of
> the Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association. List
> all sources in the reference alphabetically by name.
>
> In text citations should follow the author-date method. This means
> that the author's last name and the year of publication for the source
> should appear in the text, for example, (Jones, 1998), and a complete
> reference should appear in the reference list at the end of the paper.
>
> When a work has two authors, cite both names every time the reference
> occurs in text. When a work has three, four, or five authors, cite all
> authors the first time the reference occurs; subsequent citations
> include only the surname of the first author followed by et al., (not
> Italicized and with a period after “al.”) and the year if it is the
> first citation of the reference within a paragraph.
>
> If there are two or more citations that shorten to the same lead
> author and date, give as many additional names as needed to identify
> them, e.g., (Smith, Jones, et al., 1991) and (Smith, Burke, et al.,
> 1991).
>
> The basic reference form for a journal paper is: Author (date).Paper
> title. Journal, Volume, page; and for a book citation: Author (date).
> Book title. Place of publication, publisher.
>
> Please note that for journal articles, issue numbers are not included
> unless each issue in the volume begins with page one. Journals names
> are written out in full.
>
> Please include up to seven authors in the list (use “&” before last
> author name). For eight or more authors please list the first six and
> then use ellipses followed by last author (do not use “&” before last
> author name)

Comment: I doubt Wiley will be happy about a `biblatex`-based submission. I couldn't find any more details about LaTeX submissions on their website just now. The `apacite` package generates 6th-ed. APA style citations and bibliography.

Comment: @moewe, this is my first time submitting a manuscript. Would using `apacite` be something that Wiley would be able to work with? Overall, I am kind of nervous about preparing a manuscript with LaTeX. My concern is that Wiley/Journal of Biogeography won't have the ability to make edits to my LaTeX code, and that for every little formatting change that they might want, they would have to come back to me for it. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I couldn't find any more details about Wiley's submission process with LaTeX. Usually it is best to assume publishers don't want you to load fancy packages and don't want fancy code. On the other hand it may not always be easy to produce the exact output they want without using some fancy code. (APA style is *very* complex and doing it right requires quite some work.) Journals that are not actually typeset in LaTeX need to convert your TeX submission at some point depending on when that happens staff might be able to change the final layout then. ...

Comment: ... I guess if you want to use LaTeX it would be best to contact editorial staff and ask how they want you to deal with citations in LaTeX. They should know what their system supports. (I have seen journals that didn't really care about the LaTeX format of references: The bibliography would be regenerated later on in the correct format.) Maybe you already know someone who submitted to a Wiley journal in LaTeX: Maybe they can give you some hints.